# C# does not convert "★" correctly

Tags: c#, character-encoding

my code gets a string which can contain 2 special characters, "★" and "™".

I don't know why, but the string isn't maybe in UTF-8, but for ™ I can simply use `string1 = list["value1"].ToString().Replace("â„¢", "™");`
My problem is now that I can't find the correct code for the black star, Google did not help me. Hopefully, you can :)

Comment: Can you show this string? You could create an extension to convert the bad values as needed and have the correct string you need.

Comment: Instead of replacing [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) with the correct characters, you should read `"value1"` with the correct encoding. `"â„¢"` is UTF-8 when read using a Windows-1252 codepage. This means at some point you read from a file (or other external source) using Encoding.Default (which in general shouldn't be used), instead of the correct Encoding.UTF8.

Answer (score 0):

The black star is Unicode [symbol](https://emojipedia.org/emoji/%E2%98%85/) U+2605

```
string symbol = "\u2605";
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the code I was looking for:

â„¢ -> ™

â˜… -> ★